# Roo setup, can't execute roo from project folder

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

I'm making a GWT app with roo (new to me) and it's late at night so I'm clearly missing something but I just created a new project folder and am trying to run roo.bat (works fine when I execute the bin directory) but it won't go. I keep getting this error:

```
C:\springsource\spring-roo-1.1.4.RELEASE\newProject> ../bin/roo.bat
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Am I on crazy pills? I guess this is more of a windows command line issue but it should work (on Vista btw). Is there something about Roo.bat that won't let itself be executed from another directory or something weird?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if helps:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJe7NHbZeUw

Go to Start, My Computer, right click, Properties, Advanced Definitions, Environment Variables.

In User Variables, create JAVA_HOME, ROO_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and the path should be the installation of those apps.

Then in System Variables add also the path of roo, maven and Java separated by semicolon `;`.

Then go to start menu, type cmd, place it on desktop, like C:\Users\Martinho\Desktop
type `mkdir myApp` then enter

```
cd myApp
```

finally type `roo`.
There it is roo shell

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That was a great guide and a step by step guide of the steps in the guide NIlesh quoted. I'm just going nuts as to why it's not working. It's not even saying that 'roo' is an unknown command. It just does nothing and shows a blank prompt in the same directory.

Comment: delete your installation, download again, extract again. without setting any env variables, if you go to %ROO_INSTALL_PATH%\bin, and issue the command 'roo', what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create your projects within the Roo installation. Instead, set an environment variable as `ROO_HOME` which points to the Roo installation, and add `%ROO_HOME%/bin` to your system path.

This makes it possible to run Roo console from any location.